# wordpress redirect issue in htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some problem rewriterule in .htaccess file.
I am going to do like following for wordpress site.
when I go to http://www.test.com/test/subtest/postname on the browser, i am going to see the result same with http://www.test.com/postname
And the url  has not to be redirected 
In other words, the url of the browser has not to be changed

I tried it like following, but it dosent' work
in *.htaccess* file

**.htaccess**

```
...
RewriteRule ^test/subtest/(*)$ /$ [R=301, L]
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your regular expression match as well as the redirect.

- Use `(.*)` to match any character 0 or more times in a matching group
- Use `$1` to reference the matched group in your redirect

The `RewriteRule` should look like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^test/subtest/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301, L]
```

You can test at: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

```
output url
http://www.example.com/postname

debugging info
1  RewriteRule ^test/subtest/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301, L]   
   This rule was met, the new url is http://www.example.com/postname
   Test are stopped, because of the R in your RewriteRule options. 
   A redirect will be made with status code 301
```

Comment: in that case, the url of the browser will be changed.  i don't want to be changed the url

Comment: You should omit the `R=301` then, the `R` stands for "redirect" with a status code of `302`. The title of the question also isn't clear as it says you are trying to redirect.